# secondarynamenode on master and Datanode not start on slave hadoop 2.6.0

Tags: hadoop

when i start hadoop using `start-all.sh` after that datanode and secondarynamenode not up on server and on slave datanode not starting.
when i troubleshoot using `hdfs datanode`  get this error

```
    15/06/29 11:06:34 INFO datanode.DataNode: registered UNIX signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
15/06/29 11:06:35 WARN common.Util: Path /var/lib/hadoop/hdfs/datanode should be specified as a URI in configuration files. Please update hdfs configuration.
15/06/29 11:06:35 FATAL datanode.DataNode: Exception in secureMain
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:131)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.<init>(Groups.java:70)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.<init>(Groups.java:66)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.getUserToGroupsMappingService(Groups.java:280)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initialize(UserGroupInformation.java:271)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.setConfiguration(UserGroupInformation.java:299)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.instantiateDataNode(DataNode.java:2152)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.createDataNode(DataNode.java:2202)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.secureMain(DataNode.java:2378)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.main(DataNode.java:2402)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:129)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMapping.anchorNative()V
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMapping.anchorNative(Native Method)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMapping.<clinit>(JniBasedUnixGroupsMapping.java:49)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.JniBasedUnixGroupsMappingWithFallback.<init>(JniBasedUnixGroupsMappingWithFallback.java:39)
        ... 14 more
15/06/29 11:06:35 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1
15/06/29 11:06:35 INFO datanode.DataNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down DataNode at localserver39/10.200.208.28
```

what is issue with my datanode on slave and on master secondarynamenode  ?

```
start-dfs.sh on master
```

get this as output

```
hadoop@10.200.208.29's password: 10.200.208.28: starting datanode, logging to /home/hadoop/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hadoop-datanode-localserver39.out
10.200.208.28: nice: /usr/libexec/../bin/hdfs: No such file or directory
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
hadoop@0.0.0.0's password:
0.0.0.0: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /home/hadoop/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hadoop-secondarynamenode-MC-RND-1.out
```

After Jps get this

```
bash-3.2$ jps
8103 Jps
7437 DataNode
7309 NameNode
```

core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://10.200.208.29:9000/</value>
</property>

</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml

```
<property>
  <name>dfs.replication</name>
  <value>3</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>dfs.permissions</name>
  <value>false</value>
</property>

<property>
   <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
   <value>/Backup-HDD/hadoop/datanode</value>
</property>

<property>
        <name>dfs.namenode.data.dir</name>
        <value>/Backup-HDD/hadoop/namenode</value>
</property>


<property>
  <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
    <value>/Backup-HDD/hadoop/namenode</value>
</property>

<property>
  <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
    <value>/Backup-HDD/hadoop/datanode</value>
</property>
```

Comment: Is your `Backup-HDD` a mounted filesystem?

Comment: Don't use mounted filesystem for this purpose. It might result in permission issues. Try path like `/home/hadoop/namenode/` and `/home/hadoop/datanode/`. Make sure you create these folders and give read and write permissions.

Comment: issue is i don't have enough space in home directory.
thats y i used RAID HD...

Comment: hi, pls use
 <property>
   <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
   <value>file:/var/lib/hadoop/hdfs/datanode</value>
</property>

Comment: As @karthik said, try `/var/lib/hadoop/hdfs/datanode` or you could try `/usr/local/hadoop/namenode`. Post the result for `df - h` in your question because you have mentioned no free space in home directory.

Comment: `[hadoop@localserver39 ~]$ df -h`
`Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on`
`/dev/sdb6             4.8G  2.3G  2.3G  51% /`
`/dev/sdb11             61G   57G  1.3G  98% /home`
`/dev/sdb8             2.9G   74M  2.7G   3% /tmp`
`/dev/sdb7             3.8G  1.6G  2.1G  44% /var`
`/dev/sdb2              16G  1.3G   14G   9% /log`
`/dev/sdb3              15G  5.7G  7.8G  43% /usr`
`/dev/sdb1             190M   23M  158M  13% /boot`
`/dev/sda              549G  133M  521G   1% /backup-HDD`
this is my space my slave node

Comment: @karthik i used same configuration according to same problem

Comment: @dilshad does your namenode and data node has different user name?

Comment: @karthik same name same path on all node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the below properties from hdfs-site.xml,

```
<property>
   <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
   <value>/Backup-HDD/hadoop/datanode</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.data.dir</name>
    <value>/Backup-HDD/hadoop/namenode</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
    <value>/Backup-HDD/hadoop/namenode</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
    <value>/Backup-HDD/hadoop/datanode</value>
</property>
```

Add the below two properties in hdfs-site.xml

```
<property>
   <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
   <value>file:/home/user/Backup-HDD/hadoop/datanode</value>
</property>

<property>
    <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
    <value>file:/home/user/Backup-HDD/hadoop/namenode</value>
</property>
```

Make sure path specified in the name and data dir are exists in you system.

Comment: You have to use **dfs.namenode.name.dir** but there is "data" in your configuration.

Comment: Updated answer. You have to give the existing path. It seems /Backup-HDD path is not available in your system.

Comment: its available but i give other address too /home/hadoop/datanode

Comment: same problem.. can you send me any other website url to install hadoop on multinode

Comment: [1](http://pingax.com/install-apache-hadoop-ubuntu-cluster-setup/)
 [2](http://chaalpritam.blogspot.in/2015/01/hadoop-260-multi-node-cluster-setup-on.html) refer these.

Comment: `15/06/30 11:17:51 FATAL datanode.DataNode: Exception in secureMain
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:131)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.<init>(Groups.java:70)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.Groups.<init>(Groups.java:66)
`
error on datanode

Comment: Where you have downloaded hadoop source? Have you build it yourself? It seems you have modified some source or built wrongly.

Comment: Please delete the name and data directory then format the namenode and then try to start datanode. I think the error will not be occur when starting data node at first time. Check it once.

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved after search on google

```
Update .bashrc and .bash_profile
cat .bashrc
#!/bin/bash
unset all HADOOP environment variables
env | grep HADOOP | sed 's/.(HADOOP[^=])=.*/\1/' > un_var
while read line; do unset "$line"; done < un_var
rm un_var
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/java/latest/"
export HADOOP_PREFIX="/home/hadoop/hadoop"
export HADOOP_YARN_USER="hadoop"
export HADOOP_HOME="$HADOOP_PREFIX"
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR="$HADOOP_PREFIX/etc/hadoop"
export HADOOP_PID_DIR="$HADOOP_PREFIX"
export HADOOP_LOG_DIR="$HADOOP_PREFIX/logs"
export HADOOP_OPTS="$HADOOP_OPTS -Djava.io.tmpdir=$HADOOP_PREFIX/tmp"
export YARN_HOME="$HADOOP_PREFIX"
export YARN_CONF_DIR="$HADOOP_PREFIX/etc/hadoop"
export YARN_PID_DIR="$HADOOP_PREFIX"
export YARN_LOG_DIR="$HADOOP_PREFIX/logs"
export YARN_OPTS="$YARN_OPTS -Djava.io.tmpdir=$HADOOP_PREFIX/tmp"
cat .bash_profile
#!/bin/bash
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
source ~/.bashrc
fi
```

Issue with Bash Profile